# Pycharm Python print issue

Tags: python, printing, pycharm, python-3.6

I have some problems with PyCharm. Well I have some basic knowledge of Python 3.6 (3.6.3) and now I want to start coding on Python on PyCharm (2017.2.3), so I have downloaded Python and Pycharm.

When I try to print something like: `print('Hello World')`, it returns only:  `Process finished with exit code 0`.
But if I try with debug mode everything is ok.
[image: Picture of the code]

[image: edit configuration]

Comment: Seems like your code isn't being run. Please provide your code otherwise it's hard to tell what's happening

Comment: check your project interpreter settings

Comment: on top right you will have edit configurations can you see what is over there?

Comment: try this `print('hello',flush=True)`

Comment: ok it works now, but how to fix it to work without this?

Comment: @chakri can you help me to fix it? I mean help me please to make it work normally. Thank you

Comment: @ViktorStoyanov can i get python version and OS version you are using?

Comment: @charki Look upwards. They are there in the description from the beggining